# Swift Pass data prepareforsegue IndexPath multiple collectionViews

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I have 2 collectionViews and trying to pass data to one viewcontroller
the problem is the second collectionsView show me the indexPath of the firstCollectionView when didSelect is fired

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    if let destination = segue.destination as? DetailsViewController {
        
        let collectionView = sender as! UICollectionView
        let index = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first
        let topSeller = topSellers[index!.row]
        let topGame = topGames[index!.row]
        
        
        if collectionView.tag == 0 {
            
            
            destination.image = UIImage(named: topSeller.imageGame!)
            destination.titleGame = topSeller.titleGame
            destination.descriptionGame = topSeller.description!
            destination.youtubeURL = topSeller.youtubeURL
            destination.gameUrlBuy = topSeller.buyGameURL
        }else if collectionView.tag == 1 {
            
            
            
            destination.image = UIImage(named: topGame.imageGame!)
            destination.titleGame = topGame.titleGame
            destination.descriptionGame = topGame.description!
            destination.youtubeURL = topGame.youtubeURL
            destination.gameUrlBuy = topGame.buyGameURL
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

}

extension FirstTabViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate{

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if collectionView  == firstCollection {
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Details", sender: collectionView)
    }else if collectionView == secondCollection {
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Details", sender: collectionView)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you setting the tag?

Comment: Not related, but `let topSeller = topSellers[index!.row]` & `let topGame = topGames[index!.row]`, what happens if you have different number of items in first & second collectionView? You might have a crash here. Do it in the `if {} else {}`

Comment: You are performing the same segue in both cases. I this intended? If yes, what is the `if else` expression in `didSelectItemAt` for?

Comment: @Larme i have always the same count for both collections

Comment: @vadian Yes I know, it's the same segue destination but is the sender from the same collectionView ?

Comment: @Frankenstein Please help I'm new with iOS , where should I set the tag ?

Comment: You use `tag` in `prepare()`, and check your outlet in `didSelect`. Why no having the same behavior: `if collectionView  == firstCollection {} else {}` OR `if collectionView.tag == 0 {} else {}` , but don't mix them. If one is working, use it to differentiate your collection views...

Comment: Thanks @Larme I removed the tag and just did if collectionView == first collection { } I will do the same for second and third. God bless you